# Understanding Robin Green's derivation of the equation of the centre

Tags: taylor-expansion, mathematical-astronomy

I'm struggling to understand the derivation of the equation of the centre given in Robin Green's *Spherical Astronomy* (p147-148).

To order $e^{2}$, the [equation of the centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_the_center) is $$\nu-M=2e\sin M+\frac{5}{4}e^{2}\sin2M,\tag{1}$$ where $e$ is orbital eccentricity, $\nu$ is the true anomaly and $M$ is the mean anomaly.

Green derives the first two terms as follows.

Starting with (this is derived earlier on - a derivation I can understand)$$M=\nu-2e\sin\nu+\frac{3}{4}e^{2}\sin2\nu+O\left(e^{3}\right)\tag{2}.$$Assume $\nu=M$ to zero order in $e$. Substitute this in the second rhs term of (2) to give$$\nu=M+2e\sin M+O\left(e^{2}\right).$$And rewrite (2) as$$\nu=M+2e\sin\left(M+2e\sin M\right)-\frac{3}{4}e^{2}\sin2M+O\left(e^{3}\right).$$

Green then goes on to say: “With the usual small-angle approximations, it is found that”$$\nu-M=2e\sin M+\frac{5}{4}e^{2}\sin2M+O(e^{3)}.$$

How does he make that small angle approximation?

Comment: Small angle approximation: $\sin(M+\theta)\approx \sin M+\theta\cos M$ when $\lvert\theta\rvert\ll 1$.

Comment: @user10354138 - Thanks. That works out nicely.